# Can nbconvert join the output of multiple files?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, nbconvert

I have a bunch of ipython notebooks (`.ipynb`) that I want to convert to PDF.

I can use the following command to convert all the notebooks in a given directory.

```
jupyter nbconvert --to pdf *.ipynb
```

I was then wondering if I could output all the nbconverts to a single PDF, as if it was a book. What is the option to have a single output file? I could not find an answer in [the docs](https://nbconvert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#converting-multiple-notebooks).

Answer (score 1):

nbconvert does not have a function to do that which I could find. There are other projects that are designed to do this. The ones I could find are:

- [bookbook](https://github.com/takluyver/bookbook): This is simple and does what you're talking about
- [jupyter-book](https://github.com/executablebooks/jupyter-book): Many more features, allowing combining notebooks, markdown, and a few other things.
- [nbmerge](https://github.com/jbn/nbmerge): Really basic, combines several command line passed files into a single notebook that can then be exported using nbconvert.

Comment: I recently came across Quatro which looks to be able to do this ability to given [here](https://tutorial.quarto.org/docs/books/), [here](https://quarto.org/docs/get-started/hello/jupyter.html) and the summary on [the main page about Quatro](https://quarto.org/): "Author documents as plain text markdown or Jupyter notebooks.. Publish high-quality articles, reports, presentations, websites, blogs, and books in HTML, PDF, MS Word, ePub, and more."

Comment: Quatro looks really interesting, I hadn't found that. It looks similar in operation to Jupyter-book with more features.